# How to customize locator file to geocode unusual address?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, address, geocoding

I am very new to geocoding. I am trying to create address locator and geocode a bunch of address using ArcCatalog 10.1, and I get problem for the following addresses:

1. Road Type is in Street Name: eg: Glenview Heights Lane
2. There is direction in street name: eg: East Street
3. I have an address of 75 Romfield Cir (cir represents circuit), somehow it doesn't recongnize it even though I have added cir, circuit as a street type. I am thinking it is probably conflicting with the street type circle (cause they all start with cir).

Comment: I think the problem comes from the data used to build the locator. If your data contains the streets and address ranges you are looking for, then there should be no problem locating your unusual addresses.

Comment: Hi Maksim, thank you for your answer, i checked the reference data, it looks fine. And also if I change the address to 75 Romfield Cir to 75 Romfield Circuit, it will be geocoded. Correct me if i am wroing, but i assume it is the alternative street type problem, otherwise the circuit won't work either.